# Alert if data in certain labels is missing in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

I am sending data related to two disks to prometheus. I want to alert if metrics of one disk stops sending metrics. Say I have diskA and diskB and I am collecting disk_up metric. Now diskB failed. In prometheus

`disk_up{disk="diskA"}` will have data and 
`disk_up{disk="diskB"}` will be missing

`absent(disk_up)` will be 0 since disk_up have diskA's data. 
`absent(disk_up{disk="diskB"})` will serve the purpose. But I don't want to hardcode the disk names.

Can I know which is the better way to setup an alert for this scenario.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
max_over_time(disk_up[1h])
  unless
disk_up
```

I.e. the metric existed at any time during the past 1 hour but doesn't exist now.

You will get a false positive if a `disk_up` metric pops up for some `diskC`, though. Or if the metric gets or loses one label due to the exporter or your Prometheus configuration.

You can avoid the former by explicitly filtering for the disks/instances/whatever you are interested in, but that would defeat your goal of not hardcoding them. It is probably the wiser thing to do though:

```
max_over_time(disk_up{disk~="disk(A|B)"}[1h])
  unless
disk_up{disk~="disk(A|B)"}
```

Or at least

```
max_over_time(disk_up{job="my_disk_job"}[1h])
  unless
disk_up{job="my_disk_job"}
```

Comment: Thanks! for the quick response