# Metric to Alert when Labels are Missing Over Time

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I want to create an expression for a prometheus alert that notifies me whenever my metric doesn't have all of the possible label variations appear over a 1 hour increment. Here is an example of what my metric looks like:

`{"metric":"job_completion_time","value":1613700596,"labels":{"location":"x","slice":"control","job":"JobName","type":"a"}}`

`{"metric":"job_completion_time","value":1613700596,"labels":{"location":"y","slice":"control","job":"JobName","type":"a"}}`

This job is involved in a/b testing so I won't know all of the possible labels that will come through, and the value is unix time. At this point I just have two types since the locations are different and we're not running any a/b tests. I would rather not hardcode any values since I won't know exactly what the test slices will be named.

I thought I could use this `minute(time() - sum by (location, slice, type) (job_completion_time)) > 60`, in order to get all of the possible variations and triggered if one was absent, but it didn't work since location x showed up during the hour even though location y didn't, which prevented the alert from triggering. I can't use something like `absent_over_time(job_completion_time{location="x"}[1h])` since I would have to hardcode the locations, and potentially the other labels. Has anyone made a metric similar to this?

Edit on Nov. 29, 2021:

I used the alert expression below since I posted this question originally:

`(max_over_time(job_completion_time{job="JobName"}[1h]) unless job_completion_time{job="JobName"} OR on() vector(1)) == 1`

The idea is that once a label goes missing the max_over_time function won't return the alert value, and the vector(1) will return a 1, which will then alert us because of the == 1 logic operator.

It seems as though, this hardcoding may be the best option as referenced in this post: [Alert if data in certain labels is missing in Prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54805062/alert-if-data-in-certain-labels-is-missing-in-prometheus)

Comment: can you describe the problem you want to solve with that? I have the feeling, that there might be an easier solution like the one you described.

Comment: I wanted a flexible way to alert on various labels going missing. For example, if we had 2 locations x and y, the example above has the label example, and if location y were to go missing I would want to get alerted on the missing data without having to hardcode all of the location variations in the alert.